# What does this error mean? Python error

Tags: python

```
line = line.strip()
rsid, chromosome, position, genotype = line.split(",")
```

it is giving me a value error saying

```
ValueError: Need more than one value to unpack
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: It means your line is most likely *empty*.

Comment: That means line.split() only gives one value back. So its propably empty

Comment: `print(line.spit(','))` will show you the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you there is just *one* string in the list returned by `line.split(',')`. This means there is no comma in that string and the split returned the string unchanged, but in a list.

Usually, that means your string was empty to begin with:

```
>>> 'string with no commas'.split(',')
['string with no commas']
>>> ''.split(',')
['']
```

You can easily skip empty lines:

```
line = line.strip()
if not line:
    continue  # next iteration of the loop
rsid, chromosome, position, genotype = line.split(",")
```

You probably want to take a look at the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) rather than split file lines yourself.